# how can create in the combination the codes?

Tags: javascript, html

i have 8 li tags.. when i enter name, i want per li tag being green color..but i could not create the combination.. for example when i enter my name, one li tag will be green.. how i can create the combination ?

```
    <style>
    .color {
        background: green;
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
   }

    li{

        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: gray;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="goster">
    <ul>
   <li id="item"></li>
      <li id="item"></li>
      <li id="item"></li>
      <li id="item"></li>
      <li id="item"></li>
      <li id="item"></li>
      <li id="item"></li>
      <li id="item"></li>

    </ul>

  </div>

  <script>


        var name = prompt("Enter your name:", ""),
        li = 8,
        item="";
        while(++i < li){
            var item=document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].setAttribute("class", "color");
            document.getElementById("goster").innerHTML=name[item];
        }

  </script>
```

only i need it simply or can u give me any tips .. i tried in loop but it didnt work.. the color should be per enter name as random..

Comment: Avoid using the `innerHTML` property because it triggers a reparse, I suggest using `textContent` instead. Note that by setting the content of `<div id="goster">` you will remove the `<ul>` and all of its `<li>` children because those are children of `goster`.

Comment: And never use same `id` for multiple elements. Elements must be unique on same page.

Comment: so bro how i can create as clear ? :(

Comment: "Elements must be unique on same page." Correction: _IDs must be unique on same page._ --- Instead use classes `<li class="item"></li>` `.item{ background: green; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear what you are actually looking for.

You want to add the .color class to each li after the prompt?

```js
var name = prompt("Enter your name:", "");
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  
  let item = items[i];
  
  if(item.className.indexOf('color') < 0) {
    item.className += 'color';
    item.textContent = name;
    break;
  }
}
```

```css
.color {
        background: green;
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
   }

    li {

        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: gray;
    }
```

```html
<div id="goster">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: no bro.. i want add per single to the tag ids.. for example i entered a name, one li tag will be green, later i entered another name, another li will be green.. its what i mean..

Answer (score 0):

is this what you really want to do

```
for (var i = 0;i< li;i++){
        var item=document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].setAttribute("class", "color")
 document.getElementById("goster").children[0].children[i].textContent=name[item];
}
```

Comment: almost was true but it gave error.. all tags being green.. only i want one tag to be green..

Comment: which one do u want it to be green 
is it the one u entered it's name in prompt window ?